# Delete print settings from Microsoft Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

Microsoft Word (and probably Excel too) store some print settings inside documents. So when I print a document with specific settings, this same document on another computer use the same settings (if the printer is the same).

But sometimes this lead to problems, and it's a nightmare to solve them.

--> How can I delete print settings stored into a .doc or .docx ?

Comment: I have documents that I print at clients and in my home office. I go File, Print and then select the appropriate printer.  That does not cause me any undue difficultly.

Answer (score -2):

Select your printer and click on Manage. On the Manage your device page, you need to click on Printer properties, and then choose the desired settings in the Properties dialog for your printer.

Comment: Rose Parker - User doesn't read the question.